# Casting Derived class to base class

Tags: c++, polymorphism, overriding

I have a tricky little problem I have run into. I believe the problem has to do with the way I am casting things.

So I have a base class called `combatEntity`. It has the following function

```
class combatEntity {
public:
    virtual void update();
};
```

I then have a class mob, which is derived from `combatEntity`, overrides the update function:

```
class mob : public combatEntity {
public:
    virtual void update();

}
```

I then have a class named `monster`, which is derived from `mob` and also overrides the update function.

```
class monster: public mob {
public:
    virtual void update();
}
```

I have a combatEntity pointer called `i`:

```
combatEntity* i;
```

Then I have:

```
//returns a mob* pointer (needs explicit cast)
monster* newMonster = getMob();
i = newMonster;
```

The `getMob()` function:

```
mob* getMob() {
   mob* newMob = new mob();
   //set some data in newMob
   return newMob;
}
```

When I call `i->update()`, it calls `mob::update()`, because `newMonster` is set to "new mob();", since `getMob()` returns a new mob pointer. When I call `i->update()`, I need it to call `monster::update()`, but using breakpoints, I see it is calling `mob::update()` and not `monster::update()`.

so I need to create a new `monster` object, but still have it's base class data filled with the object returned from `getMob()`, but have the functions overridden properly. I have also tried dynamic_cast, static_cast and reinterpret_cast, and none seem to work.  Or I need to cast my base class to a derived class, while properly overriding functions with the derived class.

Hopefully this makes sence. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: monster is a mob, not the other way around. I don't see how the cast `monster* newMonster = getMob();` is implicit...

Comment: sorry, I meant it needs an explicit cast. Fixed the question.

Comment: Could you paste a little more code? Knowing how `getMob()` is working would be helpful.

Comment: You have the relationship `combatEntity <-- mob <-- monster`. How do you do this `monster* newMonster = getMob();`?

Comment: I'm confused. Your setup doesn't seem to make sense. if you say `new mob` you *don't* have a `monster`! You should very seriously follow the advice to make non-leaf classes abstract, and all your problems will go away.

Comment: If your `getMob()` does a `return new mob;`, you **should not static_cast** it to a `monster`. The latter may have uninitialized variables and a completely different v-table. You can safely use a `dynamic_cast`. This fails in your case, which is **good** because you do not have a `monster`.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster getMob() basically just returns new mob();

Comment: The line `i = monster;` makes no sense! `monster` is a **type**. Did you mean `monster * i = getMob();`? Please edit if that's the case.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I think he is doing a `i = newMonster;`

Comment: sorry, meant i = newMonster; fixed question

Comment: @Mehrwolf: I detest these pointless local variables with a vengeance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look to your hierarchy tree, make sure the classes are related how you think.

This code

```
#include <iostream>

struct combatEntity
{
    virtual void Update() { std::cout << "Combat Entity\n"; };
};

struct mob : combatEntity
{
    virtual void Update() { std::cout << "Mob\n"; };
};

struct monster : mob
{
    virtual void Update() { std::cout << "Monster\n"; };
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    combatEntity *ce = new monster;
    ce->Update();
    delete ce;

    return 0;
}
```

creates this output:

```
Monster
```

Source: http://ideone.com/k6LAB

Comment: is it possible to copy the data from a mob object into a monster object? my getMob() returns a mob object with  a bunch of variables set, and I want to copy all those variables into my monster object without manually copying them all if possible.

Comment: Don't think about copy data from one class to another; think about hierarchy: the object pointed by `combatEntity` pointer and the one created by `new monster` are the same and assigning the `new monster` pointer to `combatEntity` pointer doesn't changes the `new monster` itself or copyies anything. The only thing that happens is that you're using a `monster` as a `combatEntity`, but if the hierarchy tree is correct, the function calls ends up into to the `monster` class.

Answer (score 0):

Your line

```
monster* newMonster = getMob();
```

should not compile. I get

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘mob*’ to ‘monster*’ [-fpermissive]
```

(also your line `i = monster;` should presumably read `i = newMonster;`). This explains it all, I think (see also comment from Luchian).

Comment: yeah I have to put in an explicit cast such as static_cast, dynamic_cast or something I'm not sure which one to put. I've edited the question with a basic C cast so it compiles.

Comment: @Brad: That design is nothing short of insane.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you're using virtual, "update" will always call the correct function, no matter what you declare the pointer to be. That's just how "virtual" works.

If you want your pointers to determine what gets called, rather than the object themselves, make the stuff non-virtual. In this case, the pointer-type will determine which "update" is getting called.

If you want both, you can still call something like monster::update() instead of just update. However, unless you're doing this from inside a derived class' update function (to invoke the superclass implementation), trying to get past the inheritance hierarchy may be a sign of bad design.

Comment: From the OP's point of view `monster* m = static_cast<monster*>(new mob()); m->update();` calls the 'wrong' method `mob::update()`.

Comment: As "correct" as your suggestion may be, I cannot imagine a single situation where having multiple *non-virtual* member functions of the same name in a polymorphic class hierarchy and calling through a base pointer is ever a good idea that isn't frightfully confusing.